# How to implement ngFor callback in Angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I know that there are several questions about this point. I have a table and for each row I've a button to show row's details with a modal, so I need to call a function to initialize these buttons when ngFor has finished to render them.
This external function will add listeners "onClick" to every button to open modal, sadly I can't edit this external function anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngFor` is synchounous, so as soon as the `ngForOf` array is updated during the `ngDoCheck` lifecycle it will render all items. So you can safely use `ngAfterViewChecked` in the parent component to perform your logic. When this lifecycle hook is triggered `ngFor` has added items to the DOM.

Comment: the problem is that ngAfterViewChecked run after any viewChecked , after any cycle of ngFor the event for ngAfterViewChecked will be raised and it can not defined witch on is the last event.

Comment: @MohammadMirzaeyan, sorry, it's not clear what you mean

Comment: the problem is i want run a method or do something only once when my ngFor finished , if we use ngAfterViewChecked it's run after any change on view

Comment: @MohammadMirzaeyan, perhaps you can create a directive and place it after ngFor and inside this new directive in the ngDoCheck lifecycle hook emit an event to a component. I suspect that when `ngDoCheck` is called is executed on this new directive, ngDoCheck for `ngFor` has already been executed and that's where ngFor does rendering